# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE host lookup

Tags: mysql

I have a CSV file with a timestamp and a host IP address on each row.

The table I would like to load this file into, additionally has a hostname column.

I am trying to load this data using LOAD DATA INFILE. Is there a way I
can lookup the hostname as the data is loaded into the table?

Also as a more general question, how can I lookup the hostname for any given IP address
inside of a stored procedure, for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any MySQL function to lookup the hostname for a given IP address. I would suggest loading the data first and then looking up and missing hostnames using a script written in PHP, Ruby, Python, or whatever.